# Use $\sin,\cos$ and $\tan$ for problem solving

Tags: trigonometry

A model helicopter takes off from the horizontal ground with a constant vertical speed of $5$ m/s. After $10$ seconds the angle of elevation from Sione to the helicopter is $62$ degrees.

If Sione is $1.8$ m tall, how far is the helicopter from his head at this instant?

**Attempt**

What I did [image]

"The I represents Sione and I need to find the distance from $x$ to the tip of the triangle."

Is this diagram correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the correct diagram is this (not drawn to scale):

```
       •      ┐
      /|      │
     / |      │
  d /  |      │
   /   | 48.2 │ 50
  /    |      │
 /     |      │ 
/ 62°  |      │
•——————•  ┐   │
________  ┘1.8┘
```

The bottom left corner of the triangle is Sione's head and the top corner is the current location of the helicopter. The line at the bottom is the ground. So, $d$ is the distance between Sione's head and the helicopter.

It's very easy to solve for $d$ now.

Comment: Thanks by why is the 50m on that side? Isn't the helicopter going on an angle?

Comment: An angle of elevation does not mean that the object is traveling at that angle. [This resource](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/trigonometry/trigonometry-right-triangles/modeling-with-right-triangles/a/angles-of-elevation-and-depression) seems to explain angles of elevation and depression well. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Right so is the drone taking off from the right?

Comment: Yeah. It takes off from the ground directly in line with the vertical leg of the triangle.